# Creating a custom (select) field and update option values from php

Tags: wordpress, php

I use Wordpress with CiviCRM. I would like to create a custom select field and populate the option values with php.
After investigating the forum and the documentation I think I should create a hook (or a plugin in wordpress) for that, but not sure.

Could somebody show me a working example or direct me where to continue?

Answer (score 1):

The hook you are looking for is [hook_civicrm_customFieldOptions](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_customFieldOptions). Example from the docs:

```
function civitest_civicrm_customFieldOptions($fieldID, &$options, $detailedFormat = false ) {
    if ( $fieldID == 1 || $fieldID == 2 ) {
        if ( $detailedFormat ) {
            $options['fake_id_1'] = array( 'id'    => 'fake_id_1',
                                           'value' => 'XXX',
                                           'label' => 'XXX' );
            $options['fake_id_2'] = array( 'id'    => 'fake_id_2',
                                           'value' => 'YYY',
                                           'label' => 'YYY' );
        } else {
            $options['XXX'] = 'XXX';
            $options['YYY'] = 'YYY';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added a new plugin file for wordpress which contains this function and an add_action. Modified the FieldID in the function to refer to the proper field. 
I installed Query Monitor for WP to be able to see the hooks and the following hooks are invoked:
civicrm_instance_loaded  
civicrm_initialized  
civicrm_invoked
load-toplevel_page_CiviCRM  
toplevel_page_CiviCRM 10 CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke() Plugin: civicrm
admin_print_styles-toplevel_page_CiviCRM  
admin_print_scripts-toplevel_page_CiviCRM  
admin_head-toplevel_page_CiviCRM  
admin_footer-toplevel_page_CiviCRM